# Firebase displayName return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I sign up with gooogle or facebook I can see my displayName in console. But when I sign up with email and password I can not see displayName in console it returns null. But **interesting** part is it set display name in firebase database but can not retrieve.

```
class SignUp extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        displayName:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
        confirmPassword: ""
        }
}
// HandleChange function
handleChange = event => {
    const {value, name} = event.target;
    this.setState({[name]:value})
}
//HandleSubmit function
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {displayName, email, password, confirmPassword} = this.state;
    if(password !== confirmPassword) {
        alert("Passwords don't match ")
        return;
    }
    try {
        // firebase speacial function for email and password signins
        const {user} = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
        await createUserProfileDocument(user, {displayName, password});
        
        //clearing out the form after submit
        this.setState({
            displayName:"",
            email:"",
            password:"",
            confirmPassword: ""
        })
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message)
    }
}
render(){
```

Comment: I got the same error, I solved using https://stackoverflow.com/a/63202201/12536525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New email/password accounts in Firebase Authentication do not have a display name set.  If you want to add one after creating the account, you will have to [update the profile as described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).