# displayName return null when logged using email and password

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two options for user login,

1. using email and password
2. using google sign in

When I log using google sign in method its display name, but it not display name when using email and password, user.displayName is return null when using 1st option. I have use provider for authenticating, I have tried currentUser method also. I store users in firestore. [This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHeRC.png).[This is my users collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORp2.png)

Comment: You need to show the code and the error so other developers can help find the issue.

Comment: Gmail has its own `name` parameter (ex: my email is _email@gmail.com_ and my name is _Albert Einstein_). On the other hand, does your email and password login method has its own `name` parameter? Or your `name` and your `email` are the same? If it's not. then your name will always be `null` because the code doesn't know which one is the `name` if you logged in using email and password.

Comment: @hisam Ayrock618 I have name field in users collection. I have add error and users collections also

Comment: After I look at your images, I realize that in firebase, you set the name part with `name` and then call it in your code with `displayName`. Try to change the `name` part in your firebase to `displayName`.

Comment: @hisam no its not the problem I have changed same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user signed up using email and password, there is an option to update `displayName` and `photoUrl` of the user.

```
// Suppose currentUser is the logged in FirebaseUser

currentUser.updateProfile(
  UserUpdateInfo(
    displayName: 'name',
    photoUrl: '...',
  ),
),
```

If this was never done `displayName` and `photoUrl` will return `null`

Since you have data in `users` collection you'll have to access that data from that `document` just like u access any other `document` in firestore.

A better approach would be to accept `displayName` during sign up so that u can update `displayName` of that user:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: 'an email',
  password: 'a password',
).then((newUser) {
  newUser.updateProfile(
    UserUpdateInfo(
      displayName: 'name',
    ),
  );
});
```

Now u can access using `currentUser.displayName` directly.

Comment: Is **UserUpdateInfo** is predefined one or we need to create that method?

Comment: predefined if you have imported FirebaseAuth.